# Caption alignment of grid subfigures

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I have 5 images and I would like to display them in 2 rows (3x2). This is what I've done so far,

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{figures/figure22.png}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{figures/figure23.png}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{figures/figure24.png}} \\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{figures/figure25.png}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.8in]{figures/figure26.png}} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
```

And I'm using these packages, and I can't switch to `subcaption`:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
```

The problem is that, the captions aren't aligned to center under the subfigures. How could I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215551/cant-place-curves-side-by-side/215561?s=2|0.1089#215561

Comment: @JohnKormylo The OP says they can't switch to `subcaption`. It is not clear why, though. @ OP Take a look at `floatrow`. You can use it with `subfig`. It is a bit flaky but you can certainly do what you need here. Don't try to use a tabular though, unless you just write the captions as literal text (i.e. not captions at all), that isn't going to work. If you need more help, please provide a minimal working example. You can use images from the `mwe` package.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, and it doesn't happen when I try your code here. Does it work with other images? (If you have the `mwe` package installed, try replacing `figures/figure22.png ` with `example-image`. The `mwe` package includes several images, one of which is called `example-image`, so with the package installed you can use it directly.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was my mistake, I have used a configured template and there was a wrong caption setup in an other tex file, and I didn't notice. Btw, thanks!